# Trouble using Doctrine 2 annotation @GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")

Tags: doctrine-orm

Hope someone can help me out with this. I have the following doctrine annotation:

```
/**
 * @var integer 
 *
 * @Column(name="code", type="integer", length=4)
 * @Id
 * @GeneratedValue(strategy= "AUTO")
 */
private $code;
```

Where code is my table Primary Key. 
What I want is the code value to be properly set (automatically) every time a row is inserted in the table.

I'm using Doctrine 2 and PostgreSQL and the problem is this:
In order to prepare the DB in advance I insert rows into the table using SQL commands directly in PgAdmin.
Then I try inserting new rows but this time through my program and every time I try to insert this row I get a Primary Key conflict until I've tried as many times as rows inserted before with SQL commands.

For example if I've inserted 3 rows using SQL commands, I'd have to try 3 times using the program and by the 4th atempt the row would be properly inserted.

Is there any way to set the initial Primary Key value to 4 (Of course this value depends on the number of rows already inserted using SQL commands before running the program) to avoid the Primary Key conflicts?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think you inserted values in your table manually self assigning a the value of the code:

`insert into table (code, ... ) values (1, ...)`

In that case your serial value will not be incremented. So when Doctrine tries to insert a new row to the database, it will use the serial for the auto numbering. The serial status is still at value 1, which causes a Primary key conflict. Although the query failed, the serial is incremented by one, so the next time it will try to use the value `2`. This explains why after three attempts, you don't get a Primary Key conflict anymore.

Hope this explanation helps.

Good luck!